# Laravel: How to create variables from database and access values in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having a problem/designing question for laravel 5.4 experts.

I've a website with different "companies":
example.com/company1
example.com/company2 etc.

I've a table "companies" which contains the data for the companies like ("id","name" etc). The page is displayed using a blade template.

I now like to have a set of "sections" on each page. Like "company_history", "company_employees" etc. These sections should be defined by my admin dashboard as new sections are added from time to time. I have these sections defined in a table "sections" which has an "sectionId" and a "name" column.

Additionally I've a table "content" which has the columns "id", "companyId" and "sectionId" and "content".

I now like to have displayed the content for the current company by using something like {{ $content['company_history'] }} in the view template.

At the moment I create an array in the controller for that page by going through each item of "sections" and getting the content for each value from the "content" table. The 'content' column holds the content which should be displayed.

Is there better solution to do this?
I already tried using "belongsToMany" in the model, but I think this this is only working with "real" pivot tables.

Any idea? I'm open to any solutions :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to tackle this. The lazy solution which you may like is to just serialize it into a column in company.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

This avoids all the problems with separate tables and joins.

This is not ideal if you need to search by the content (eg. Product attributes) but in your case, it shouldn't be a problem.